# Student position in exams giving me errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a student database and will like to get the position of a student in his class based on the subject results in column `f_score`.

I am getting an error which says:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

I am using VB.NET and Microsoft SQL Server 2012. These codes are MySQL and I want to re-write them to SQL Server. This is the code I am using:

```vb
Dim str1 As String = "SELECT studentid, f_score, FIND_IN_SET(  sum(f_score),
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sum(f_score) 
    ORDER BY sum(f_score) DESC ) FROM assessment )) AS rank 
FROM assessment where studentid='" & strid & "' and stuclass='" & strclass & "'; "`
```

The SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    studentid, 
    f_score, 
    FIND_IN_SET(sum(f_score), 
        (SELECT 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sum(f_score) ORDER BY sum(f_score) DESC) 
        FROM assessment
        )
    ) AS rank 
FROM 
    assessment 
WHERE
    studentid='" & strid & "' and stuclass='" & strclass & "'; "
```

Below is my database

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is MySQL syntax not SQL Server.

To achieve this in SQL Server you would use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql)

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT studentid,
               f_score = SUM(f_score),
               rank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(f_score) DESC)
        FROM   assessment
        WHERE  stuclass = @StuClass
        GROUP  BY studentid) T
WHERE  studentid = @StudentId;
```

Also you are open to SQL injection. You should use parameterised queries.

See this link for [how to use parameters in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)